# How to set a location to be validated through GPS on Ionic 2?

Tags: android, gps, ionic2

I'm developing an app on Ionic 2 and I would like to implement a restriction where a certain functionally can only be used if the user is GPS located on a location, or within a range, I have set on my database. For example: The user can click on the item only if he is at X. I am recently new to Ionic 2 and how GPS validation work.

What would be the best approach to accomplish this restriction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to accomplish is called "geofencing".
Generally, your application will obtain a location and then check if the coordinates of the last known location are withing a set of predefined regions, usually in a radius around some other coordintate.

Some mobile sdks provide implementation for geofencing, however since you are using ionic2 you may have to look into cordova implementations.

Luckly enough, someone put an [example of geofencing with ionic2](https://github.com/tsubik/ionic2-geofence) and you should definetly take a look.

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I was looking for.